# Using Windows 10 UWP WebAccountManager with Google OAuth or MSA

Tags: c#, authentication, google-oauth, uwp, microsoft-account

I'm trying to use WebAccountManager for making login easier in a Windows 10 Universal Windows App (UWP).

It seems like the documentation around how to use WebAccountManager is somewhat lacking. Are Microsoft Account (MSA) and AAD the only WebAccountProvider implementations that come out of the box?

Did anyone have any luck making this work, and have code to share?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking into the wrong namespace. Take a look at this namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.aspx

Comment: Great! Based on Channel9 and MSDN I thought the goal was to have it replaced by [WebAccountManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.provider.webaccountmanager.aspx) which leverages the existing accounts associated with Windows, but WebAuthenticationBroker would do the trick :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The identity providers unsupported by WebAccountManager can be added to the authentication prompt using the [WebAccountProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager#add-providers-that-dont-support-webaccountmanager) class.

Getting the access token of the new provider is the responsibility of the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker) class.

**Note**: You may also want to use the newer [MSAL.net](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) library instead. It appears to be equivalent to the WebAccountManager and there's also a [simple UWP code example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp/blob/master/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-uwp/MainPage.xaml.cs) available.